# Problem with derivating integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic

I have a doubt :
I know that if $x_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}\gamma(s)dW_{s}$ (with $W_{s}$ a brownian motion), we have : 
$dx_{t}=\gamma(t)dW_{t}$
What about if $x_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}\gamma(s,t)dW_{s}$. Do I have to apply a kind of Lieibniz rule to get $dx_{t}$ ? If so what is  the result  ?
Tx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume that $\gamma(s, t)$ is differentiable with respect to $t$. Then,
\begin{align*}
dx_t = \left(\int_0^t \frac{\partial\gamma(s, t)}{\partial t} dW_s \right)dt + \gamma(t, t) dW_t.
\end{align*}

Comment: I see  in the meantime a similar answer on Willmott:

http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=51005

But it's $...dW_{t})dt$ or $...dW_{s})dt$ ?

And what about the quadratic variation : do we have : $d<x>_{t}=\gamma(t,t)^2dt$ ? Seems like I missing the 1st term though ...

Comment: The first is a $dt$ term, which disappears for quadratic variation.

Comment: ok thank you. And what about my 1st question : is it :
$...dW_{t})dt$ or $...dW_{s})dt$ Many thanks

Comment: sorry, that was typo, which I have corrected.